# group by and select non null value if present

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way I can perform `group by` and use non value for a column if any. i.e

```
a  | b | c | d    | e       | f                   |
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 2 | 3 | x    | test1   | 2019-07-01 07:17:01 |
1  | 2 | 3 | NULL | test2   | 2019-07-01 10:23:11 |
1  | 2 | 3 | NULL | test3   | 2019-07-01 22:00:51 |
1  | 2 | 7 | NULL | testTet | 2019-07-01 23:00:00 |
```

In my case above if `d` is present for say `a=1,b=2,c=3` it will always be `x` otherwise it can come null. So my query would be like

```
select a,
       b,
       c,
       d,
       count(distinct e) as something
from tableX
where f between '2019-07-01 00:00:00' and '2019-07-01 23:59:59.999'
group by a,
         b,
         c,
         d
```

the results would be:

```
a  | b | c | d    | something |
------------------------------|
1  | 2 | 3 | x    | 1         |
1  | 2 | 3 | NULL | 2         |
1  |2  | 7 | NULL | 1         |
```

whereas it will be wonderful if I can have (since for each `group by` combination I know it's null or that unique value if present):

```
a  | b | c | d    | something |
------------------------------|
1  | 2 | 3 | x    | 3         |
1  | 2 | 7 | NULL | 1         |
```

Comment: What if you had multiple d values for a=1,b=2,c=3 and also a null d value? What would the null default to?

Comment: @GreyOrGray `d` is unique for `a`=1,`b`=2,`c`=3. i.e `d` can either be `NULL` or that unique value for each combination. So I just want to capture it if available.

Comment: Gotcha, in that case either answer below works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your sample data I think that you don't need `d` in the `group by` clause. 
So get its max:

```
select 
  a, b, c, 
  max(d) d,
  count(distinct e) as something
from tableX
where f between '2019-07-01 00:00:00' and '2019-07-01 23:59:59.999'
group by a, b, c
```

Comment: wow. how does `max` work for non numeric? I thought it's gonna spit some errors or return `NULL` instead of letter `a`. excuse my noobness :)?

Comment: Max works for any data type that is comparable. So for strings any non null string is greater than null.

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
with cte as (select a,
       b,
       c,
       d,
       count(distinct e) as something
from tableX
where f between '2019-07-01 00:00:00' and '2019-07-01 23:59:59.999'
group by a,
         b,
         c,
         d) select a,b,c,max(d) as d,sum(something) from cte group by a,b,c
```